# Minify JS cause an error in my store

Tags: magento2, theme, optimization

I'm building a store using Magento CMS. It was all working fine, however a bit slow and so I decided to take some steps to optimize the store.

The first one was the minify of the files. However, when I did this the store broke and I can not roll back because the dashboard also does not work. When I click the links on the sidebar they do not point anywhere.

Thank you very much in advance. Need help.

Comment: try reverting the setting from db table `core_config_data`, then clear cache from command line.

Comment: @GeekSilva you'd need to redeploy static content from CLI command after you configured Minify JS

Comment: @TuyenNguyen with `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`?

Comment: It works! Sorry for this very simple question.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I did deploy of static contents and it worked. The command that I used was `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`